# Multiple Nested Routes, is there a better way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-resources

So In my rails app I have two resources (rentals, and reservations) which belong to a user.  This is the code in my routes.rb to set up the nested routes.

```
  map.resources :users, :has_many => :reservations, :shallow => true
  map.resources :users, :has_many => :rentals, :shallow => true
  map.resources :rentals, :only => [:index]
  map.resources :reservations, :only => [:index]
```

Is there a more perferred way to do this.  I've done some googling but I can't find a clear answer.

Thanks in advance.

-ray

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method duplicates the routes for users, as you can see by running `rake routes`. You can fix that by passing a block to `map.resources`:

```
map.resources :users, :shallow => true do |user|
  user.resources :reservations
  user.resources :rentals
end
```

The nested routes created will assume that you always want to access those resources in a nested fashion.

If you really need all the routes you've defined (including the non-nested rentals and reservations index) then you will need to add:

```
map.resources :rentals, :only => [:index]
map.resources :reservations, :only => [:index]
```

And I don't know of a DRYer way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can define nested routes with blocks

```
map.resources :users, :shallow => true do |user|
  user.resources :reservations, :only => [:index]
  user.resources :rentals, :only => [:index]
end
```

I feel that this way is a bit more clear and can more easily be adjusted later when you need additional options on one of the nested resources.

The different options and the details are at the [ActionController Resources API page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html)

Comment: Same comment as I left on kchau's answer: this does not create all the routes as the original.

Answer (score 1):

Nests the two resources under users:

```
  map.resources :users, :shallow => true do |users|
    users.resources :reservations, :only => :index
    users.resources :rentals, :only => :index
  end
```

Edit: Sorry, forgot the :shallow option.

Comment: This does not create all the routes as the original. The OP has a full list of nested routes, plus one non-nested route (index).

Comment: ScottJ is right, my code snippet will only produce a subset of the routes that OP wants.